# CakePHP2.2 error missing helper on subdomain

Tags: cakephp, subdomain

I am getting a Missing Helper error.

**Error: htmlHelper could not be found.**

It is working fine on my local machine. Then i upload it to my sub domain, but when I run it, the error message appears. I don't change the directory structure or coding inside. I just upload it. But cannot run.

Is it my hosting problem here?
Is it file .htaccess affected if my hosting doesn't support mod_rewrite?

```
http://jendelatekaje.net/ => is my domain
http://jendelatekaje.net/latiefz/ = http://latiefz.jendelatekaje.net/8
i upload my cake to latiefz.jendelatekaje.net
```

Is there any answer for my question?

Answer (score 7):

It says `htmlHelper could not be found.`
It's **HtmlHelper**, with capital H. Check where you call HtmlHelper, probably in your AppController.
You must have something like `public $helpers = array('Html',...)` instead of `public $helpers = array('html',...)`.

Comment: Yep...I just had this same problem and for some reason "html" is not case sensitive on my local machine but it is when I upload it online. So I had to change `$this->html->link()` to `$this->Html->link()`.

Comment: I think your explanation at the end there is opposite, prob he develops on windows and uploads to unix based server i had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I could not find a solution. I was not calling HtmlHelper in any place so I run out some tests. I push all modifications to git repository and clone it in a windows environment and everything had worked perfectly. 
So back in linux I still had the problem so I think it's definitely a case-sensitive problem.

To solve the problem I had to do a modification in AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    // [...]
    public $helpers = array('Html');
}
```

I know it's no a real solution, but it allowed me to keep working on my project. I'm using with cakePhp 2.3.0.